# Expo secrets, unable to access in prod

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

The expo documentation is either confusing or wrong.
In my app.config.js i have:

```
export default {
  expo: {
...
    extra: {
      API_URI: process.env.API_URI,
      API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
    },
...
```

In consts.js :

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
...
export const { API_URI, API_KEY } = Constants.manifest.extra
```

When I export API_URI and API_KEY env vars on my local box, `expo start` works just fine (does not work without the exports which is expected).

When I create build with `eas build` and submit it to the app store -- the app in the test flight can never connect to the API as it can't find the config values. I have created the secrets via expo UI -- nada.

It does not have to be this complicated. What am I missing?
Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Got my answer here
https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1265#issuecomment-1301525320
I do wish expo simplified/cleaned their documentation a bit and made like one simple example which just works out of the box instead of providing tons of information where it's so easy to miss `Constants.expoConfig` vs `Constants.manifest`